# Symfony2: How do i generate sha512 hash of a password?

Tags: php, hash, symfony, fosuserbundle, sha512

I need to compare the password entered by the user if it is valid or not. How do i get the sha512 encryption. I am also using FOSUserBundle in my project.

Comment: Take a look at my [Blowfish password encoder bundle](https://github.com/elnur/ElnurBlowfishPasswordEncoderBundle).

Comment: Hey thanks for this link. Its great. Will try it out.

Comment: As a variant you can get instance of encoder and use it's encode method. Look at the encoder class in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18291974/251735

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your controller you can do (assuming that you set sha512 as encoding algorithm in `app/config/security.yml`)

```
    $userName = 'username';
    $password = "pass";
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user = $userManager->loadUserByUsername($userName);
    $encoder = $this->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
    $encodedPass = $encoder->encodePassword($password, $user->getSalt());
    echo $user->getPassword() === $encodedPass;
```

Comment: I was just wondering what would be the logic if i want to validate a users password even if he is logged in, in case to redirect him for some secure page. So how is the comparison of passwords done in this scenario. Thanks @m2mdas

Comment: You can check [this](http://kriswallsmith.net/post/15994931191/symfony2-security-voters) article. Haven't tried it though.

Comment: This did not work for me.  This did: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/696

Answer (score 4):

Symfony has several different ways to store passwords. The logic to hash and check the password is stored in several ["Encoder" classes](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder):

- [BCryptPasswordEncoder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/BCryptPasswordEncoder.php)
- [MessageDigestPasswordEncoder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php)
- [Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder.php)
- [PlaintextPasswordEncoder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/PlaintextPasswordEncoder.php)

Which one is used [can be configured in security.yml](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html), under the key `encoder`. If this says `sha512`, you are using the `MessageDigestPasswordEncoder`.

The encoder type can be different for different user types. To get the correct encoder for a user, you can ask the [EncoderFactory](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/EncoderFactory.php). This is already done for you in the [UserPasswordEncoder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/UserPasswordEncoder.php): you pass a user and a plain password to `UserPasswordEncoder->isPasswordValid`, and it checks the password with the correct encoder belonging to this user. This is the easiest interface to check a user's password.

If you really want to know how the SHA512 hashing works, you can check [MessageDigestPasswordEncoder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php). It [combines the salt and password](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/BasePasswordEncoder.php#L68) in a string like "password{salt}". It computes the hash of this [string 5000 times](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php#L58). This is to make the password hash slow, so it is not easy to brute-force.

When checking whether the password is valid, [it uses `hash_equals`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/BasePasswordEncoder.php#L84). This is a constant-time comparison, which prevents timing attacks on the password hash.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure it's SHA512 you need, try [this](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php).

Comment: I tried this but was not getting correct hash somehow! I guess FOSUserBundle uses the salt to encode the passwords.