# Salted sha512 in C, cannot synchronise with Symfony2's FOSUserBundle

Tags: c, symfony, fosuserbundle, sha512

My developement is separated into two components :

- The website, a Symfony application using FOSUserBundle, which encrypts password using SHA512, and a salt.
- An authentication module, programmed in C, which should be able to reproduce the SHA512 salted hash once it's given the salt, and the cleartext password.

### Some information about my environment

- I'm using Linux Ubuntu 12.04.
- `ldd --version` answers *EGLIBC 2.15-0ubuntu10.4 2.15* (maybe I need 2.7 ? But `apt-get` is a real PAIN when it comes to upgrading packages correctly).
- The `crypt.h` header files mentions *@(#)crypt.h  1.5 12/20/96*

### The problem itself

My problem occurs in the authentication module : I'm unable to get the same hash as the one produced by Symfony's FOSUserBundle. Here's my example :

- The password salt, used by Symfony, is `bcccy6eiye8kg44scw0wk8g4g0wc0sk`.
- The password itself is `test`

With this information, Symfony stores this final hash :

```
fH5vVoACB4e8h1GX81n+aYiRkSWxeu4TmDibNChtLNZS3jmFKBZijGCXcfzCSJFg+YvNthxefHOBk65m/U+3OA==
```

Now, in my C authentication module, I run this piece of code (`crypt.h` is included) :

```
char* password = "test";
char* salt = "$6$bcccy6eiye8kg44scw0wk8g4g0wc0sk";

char* hash = malloc(256);
memset(hash, 0, 256);

encode64(crypt(password, salt), hash, strlen(password));
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", hash);
```

(here is my base64 encoder : http://libremail.tuxfamily.org/sources/base64-c.htm)

And this outputs...

```
JDYkYg==
```

Which is completely different from my Symfony2 hash.

Browsing Stack Overflow, I found this question ([Symfony2 (FOSUserBundle) SHA512 hash doesn't match C# SHA512 hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325341/symfony2-fosuserbundle-sha512-hash-doesnt-match-c-sharp-sha512-hash)) written by someone encountering the same issue (with C# though). So I decided to run this test...

```
char* password = "test{bcccy6eiye8kg44scw0wk8g4g0wc0sk}";
char* salt = "$6$bcccy6eiye8kg44scw0wk8g4g0wc0sk"; // I tried without salt, or with "$6$" as well.

char* hash = malloc(256);
memset(hash, 0, 256);

encode64(crypt(password, salt), hash, strlen(password));
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", hash);
```

Of course, it was a complete failure, I got :

```
JDYkYmNjY3k2ZWl5ZThrZzQ0cyRycmN6TnpJUXFOYU1VRlZvMA==
```

I've tried mixing the password and the salt in various ways, but I could never get the Symfony's salt in the authentication module. Is there something I've missed on the way ? Have I misunderstood the way Symfony's FOSUserBundle stores passwords ?

Comment: Is `crypt` on your system definitely using SHA512?

Comment: By using `$6$` in the salt, I define the encryption as `sha512`, right ?

Comment: Do you have some system (or C library) documentation that indicates that this should be true?

Comment: `man -s2:3 crypt` is enough of a proof to me, I'd say : *"If salt is a character string starting with the characters "$id$" followed by a string terminated by "$", then instead of using the DES machine, id identifies the encryption method used and this then determines how the rest of the password string is interpreted."*

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable (glibc 2.1+ ?). Could you please update your question to specifically mention the OS/platform and library versions you're dealing with? (especially C libraries and hardware)

Comment: Done. I realised that my GLIBC version might me invalid (SHA512 arrived at glibc 2.7), but `apt-get` won't let me upgrade at any higher version...

Comment: I think your question is now entirely valid. Let's hope someone more familiar with either implementation can see the issue.

Comment: My suggestion would to write a little stand alone PHP program which does the thing as your C program.  See if you can get the same results without Symfony being in the mix.  If you can't then that helps to isolate the problem to simple php allowing folks not familiar with symfony to help.  If you can get the results to match then you can easily write your own symfony password encoder or start focusing on exactly where the default symfony encoder differs from yours.  Might be something as simple as setting an option.

Comment: I would also suggest that you test your C program on your production machines before going much further.  Be sad if you got this working on your your particular development machine and then have it break when it's gets moved to production.

Comment: As a system administrator, I have full rights to extend the production server for my module. Working with a PHP script would require me to execute a direct system call in C, which is not really a proper way... :s `crypt` should be **able** to generate a salted sha512 hash since glibc 2.7, which is, just like many packages, unavailable through `apt-get`. I'll have to find another workaround.

Comment: I wasn't clear.  My php suggestion was just to isolate the problem down to few lines of code you which you can execute from a command line with "php encode.php".  PHP already has a bunch of crypt functions.  Use them.  Once the problem is solved then the php script can go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really an answer but I'm guessing you have not looked into how Symfony encodes passwords in any great detail?  The encoding process is tucked away into an encoder object.  For SHA512 we use:

```
namespace Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder;

class MessageDigestPasswordEncoder extends BasePasswordEncoder
{
/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param string  $algorithm          The digest algorithm to use
 * @param Boolean $encodeHashAsBase64 Whether to base64 encode the password hash
 * @param integer $iterations         The number of iterations to use to stretch the password hash
 */
public function __construct($algorithm = 'sha512', $encodeHashAsBase64 = true, $iterations = 5000)
{
    $this->algorithm = $algorithm;
    $this->encodeHashAsBase64 = $encodeHashAsBase64;
    $this->iterations = $iterations;
}
public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
{
    if (!in_array($this->algorithm, hash_algos(), true)) {
        throw new \LogicException(sprintf('The algorithm "%s" is not supported.', $this->algorithm));
    }

    $salted = $this->mergePasswordAndSalt($raw, $salt);
    $digest = hash($this->algorithm, $salted, true);

    // "stretch" hash
    for ($i = 1; $i < $this->iterations; $i++) {
        $digest = hash($this->algorithm, $digest.$salted, true);
    }

    return $this->encodeHashAsBase64 ? base64_encode($digest) : bin2hex($digest);
}
public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt)
{
    return $this->comparePasswords($encoded, $this->encodePassword($raw, $salt));
}
protected function mergePasswordAndSalt($password, $salt)
{
    if (empty($salt)) {
        return $password;
    }

    if (false !== strrpos($salt, '{') || false !== strrpos($salt, '}')) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Cannot use { or } in salt.');
    }

    return $password.'{'.$salt.'}';
}
```

As you can see, one immediate problem is that hashing is repeated 5000 times by default.  This (as well as the other inputs can all be adjusted in you app/config/security.yml file).

You can also see where the salt and password get merged together.  Which explains the other stackoverflow answer.

It would be trivial to make a symfony command to just run this encoding algorithm from the symfony console for testing.  After that is just a question of adjusting the inputs or tweaking your C code until the results match.

If you are lucky then all your will have to do is add the iteration loop.

Comment: I didn't think about reading this piece of code indeed, the iteration part is certainly where I've missed something ! I don't think any better answer could be given, so I'm going to close this. I'll study this code by modifying it for test purposes, and reproduce the same algorithm in C. Thank you !

Comment: you may want to check sources here https://github.com/symfony/security/blob/master/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php